# Text watermark in CE Image

Tags: ce-image

I see an option in CE Image to add watermark to an image, but that watermark -- based on the example I saw -- is an image. Is it possible to watermark an image with plain text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, take a look at the [text= parameter](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/parameters#text). :)

Comment: No worries. There are a lot of parameters, and it can be easy to miss one.